# how to prove ⊢ P↔P using natural deduction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

how to prove  ⊢ P↔P using natural deduction?

[image: Here is my proof]

I don't know whether I was correct or not.

Comment: the proof is correct, although, depending on your audience and the amount of rigor they expect, you may way to provide justification for assuming $p \rightarrow p$ as a true premise

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Actually, this proof really isn't correct. All it shows is that $(P \to P) \to (P \to P)$

Comment: @Bram28 it is not difficult to show that $p \rightarrow p$, which he assumes as a true premise, is in fact a true premise. This is why I said his proof is correct but in need of further development. He has the "correct idea" but not the necessary rigor to go along with.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Right, it's not difficult ... but the OP did not do this ... or any part towards showing $P \leftrightarrow P$. So, I don't think it even had the "correct idea". I'll concede I'm in a cranky mood today though. Maybe tomorrow I'll be more forgiving :)

Comment: I agree with you, but I dont want to agree with you lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is incorrect as it is. Using $\to$ Intro after the outside subproof will get you $(P \to P) \to (P \to P)$, rather than $P \leftrightarrow P$

To get $P \leftrightarrow P$, you have to do a subproof that assumes $P$ and that concludes $P$ (this takes either a Reiteration of $P$, or you can just close the subproof immediately after assuming $P$.

Then, depending on how the $\leftrightarrow$ Intro rule is defined, you either conclude $P \to P$ using $\to$ Intro, and then point to this statement twice, or point to the subproof twice.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.