# How to derive $A$ from $A$ in First Order Logic

Tags: logic, solution-verification, natural-deduction

I want to derive $A$ from $A$, here is what I have done :

0. A hypothese
1. $A$ (AA)

   1.1 $¬A$ (AA)

   1.2 $A$ (Negation Elimination from 1.1)
2. $A -> A$ (Introduction -> (1-1.2))
3. $A$ (MP(0,2))

Is this a good way to prove what I want ? Or I can't do that in derviation ?

Comment: Not necessary.... $A \vdash A$ is a [valid derivation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Assumption/Proof_Rule).

Comment: Thank you, but since I don't have this rule in my course, I think I have to do that mechanically

Comment: The definition of *derivation* in ND must start with a "one line" rule: "Let $\varphi$ be a formula. Then $\varphi$ is a derivation: its conclusion is $\varphi$, and it has one undischarged assumption,
namely $\varphi$." Thus, if we use the general form of derivation $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$, we have that $\{ \varphi \} \vdash \varphi$ is a correct derivation.

Comment: Duplicate. See the question [How to prove $\vdash p \to p$ using Hilbert axioms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923329/how-to-prove-vdash-p-to-p-using-hilbert-axioms).

Comment: I don't want to use Hilbert Axioms, just derivation rules like Introduction / Elimination.

Comment: Then use this one: [how to prove ⊢ P↔P using natural deduction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3406587/754923)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one line proof:

0. A (hypothesis)

QED